# Strip shortcode from specific post types (formats)

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, post-formats

I am trying to remove the shortcode from a specific post type, in this case link. I used this code on my functions.php but it removes the shortcode from the_content for every post type.

```
<?php
function remove_shortcodes( $content )
{
    return strip_shortcodes( $content );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcodes' );
```

is it possible to modify this so it only remove the shortcode from "Link" post type?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use [WordPress Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Post_Type) to query if this page is the custom post type you are wanting to target and then if it is remove shortcode.

Untested but you can try this:

```
    function remove_shortcodes( $content ) {

        if ( get_post_type() == 'post-type-name' ) {
            return strip_shortcodes( $content );
        }
        else 
            return $content;
    }

add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcodes' );
```

Comment: It's interesting that you two both forgot to return the `$content` when the "if" fails.

Comment: Haha yeah you are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will remove shortcodes for the link post type. Maybe you wanna combine it with [is_main_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)

```
<?php
function remove_shortcodes( $content )
{
    if ( 'link' == get_post_type() ) // change it to the post type you want
        return strip_shortcodes( $content );
    else
        return $content;

}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcodes' );
?>
```

Comment: Now returning the content